# libreoffice Python Uno support for Python 2.7 on Ubuntu Saucy 13.10

Tags: 13.10, python, libreoffice, python-2.7

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 and discovered that the python-uno package is no longer available.  Instead I find a python3-uno package.  Unfortunately I need Python uno libreoffice support for Python 2.7, since I'm trying to use Appy POD (http://appyframework.org/pod.html), which does not yet support Python 3.  Any ideas how I can add support to my existing Ubuntu packages or is there a PPA or something I can get a version of libreoffice which does have support for Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/418550/4397
In a few words: python2 support is dropped in deb packages for LibreOffice since Ubuntu 13.10. You can also recompile libreoffice with this script https://gist.github.com/hbrunn/6f4a007a6ff7f75c0f8b

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 13.10 and later versions, you need to install OpenOffice 4.1.1 manually.

1. Remove the previous version:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove libreoffice* openoffice*
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
2. Installation Apache OpenOffice 4.1.1

   on 64-bit Ubuntu:

   ```
   wget sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.1/binaries/en-GB/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
   tar -xzvf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
   cd en-GB/DEBS
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   cd desktop-integration
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

   on 32-bit Ubuntu:

   ```
   wget sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.1/binaries/en-GB/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
   tar -xzvf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
   cd en-GB/DEBS
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   cd desktop-integration
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```
3. touch uno.pth for python2.7

   ```
   echo /opt/openoffice4/program |sudo tee /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uno.pth
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an up-to-date script for building and installing LibreOffice 4.4.7.2 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 from [here](https://gist.github.com/nicktime/364a80ad0e083948b9f873640e50fe89):

```
#!/bin/bash -xe

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep libreoffice
sudo apt-get install pkg-config

mkdir libreoffice
cd libreoffice
wget https://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/4.4.7.2/src/libreoffice-4.4.7.2.tar.xz
wget https://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/4.4.7.2/src/libreoffice-dictionaries-4.4.7.2.tar.xz
wget https://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/4.4.7.2/src/libreoffice-help-4.4.7.2.tar.xz
wget https://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/4.4.7.2/src/libreoffice-translations-4.4.7.2.tar.xz

tar -xf libreoffice-4.4.7.2.tar.xz 
tar -xf libreoffice-dictionaries-4.4.7.2.tar.xz 
tar -xf libreoffice-help-4.4.7.2.tar.xz 
tar -xf libreoffice-translations-4.4.7.2.tar.xz 

cd libreoffice-4.4.7.2/
export PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.7 PYTHON_CFLAGS="$(pkg-config --cflags python-2.7)" PYTHON_LIBS="$(pkg-config --libs python-2.7)"
./autogen.sh --with-package-format=deb --enable-epm
make -j6

sudo dpkg -i workdir/installation/LibreOffice_Dev/deb/install/LibreOfficeDev_4.4.7.2_Linux_x86-64_deb/DEBS/*.deb
# SDK, optional.
# sudo dpkg -i workdir/installation/LibreOffice_Dev_SDK/deb/install/LibreOfficeDev_4.4.7.2_Linux_x86-64_deb_sdk/DEBS/lodevbasis4.4-sdk_4.4.7.2-2_amd64.deb 
sudo apt-get install -f

echo /opt/libreofficedev4.4/program | sudo tee /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uno.pth
```

And then uno needs this code to run properly:

```
# XXX: LibreOffice UNO bootstrap.
sys.path.append('/opt/libreofficedev4.4/program')
os.putenv('URE_BOOTSTRAP', 'vnd.sun.star.pathname:/opt/libreofficedev4.4/program/fundamentalrc')
```

it can be put right at the top of `/opt/libreofficedev4.4/program/uno.py` (it's hacky though, those changes will be lost if you upgrade the package).