# How do I install the 'python-uno' package?

Tags: apt, python, openoffice.org

I had a script, it is working with the package `python-uno` on Ubuntu 12.04 lts. The script is in python language and work with OOo to edit XLS files.

Now I upgraded to 13.10 and it seems the uno not working on this release.

Is there any other solution that work like python-uno? Or how can I know when the uno will be available for 13.10 ?!

UPDATE:
i upgraded this ubuntu server with 'do-release-upgrade' and after update i got 'cant import uno package' in logs
so tried to install python-uno from command line and i show this message :

```
peiman@digidoc:~$ sudo apt-get install python-uno
[sudo] password for peiman:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package python-uno is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libreoffice-script-provider-python

E: Package 'python-uno' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you read the message it says:

```
Package python-uno is not available, but is referred to by another package.  
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or  
is only available from another source  
However the following packages replace it:
  libreoffice-script-provider-python
```

Hence, what to do, instead of python-uno install `libreoffice-script-provider-python` instead:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-script-provider-python
```

This will install `python3-uno` package, and the interface for LO to use UNO.

`python-uno` package was removed:

```
libreoffice (1:4.1.0-2ubuntu1) saucy; urgency=low

  * unfuzz Ubuntu palette patch
  * remove sessioninstaller for wizards patch -- they are all python now
  * remove python-uno (Python 2 bridge)
  * trying to remove the workdir before installing on ppa builds to squeeze in
    size requirements
  * smaller src-tarballs
  * do not run subsequentchecks in build anymore, as we can run them as an
    autopkgtest, which is better, and eases distress caused by PPA buildds
    being storage contrained
  * use system orcus for real
  * remove double echo
  * merge with upstream
  * use system lpsolve and graphite
  * kill of csh stuff for good
  * clean up dupes in -core breaks against -evolution
  * remove dbghelp.dll binary from tarball creation
  * silence lintian on the copyright file
  * make -dbg use python3-uno proper
  * fix build against poppler 0.23/0.24

 -- Bjoern Michaelsen   Thu, 01 Aug 2013 20:17:26 +0200
```

Comment: i installed the listed pakage but dont worked the same!
it dont work the same! how can i know when the python-uno will release for 13.10

Comment: @peimanF. python-uno was dropped of all ubuntu versions, it will not come back.

Comment: i changed my code to 'python3 /var/www/dg2/inc/DocumentConverter.py' but got this error:
  File "/var/www/dg2/inc/DocumentConverter.py", line 130
    raise DocumentConversionException, "failed to connect to OpenOffice.org on port %s" % port
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: and open office is running for me   peiman@digidoc:/usr/bin$ sudo netstat -nap | grep office
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2794171  4301/soffice.bin    /tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_84166f53c65d9ded4d416e24fa9b5d8

Comment: There are several things that must be changed in your code to make it python3 compatible http://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html

Comment: thank you for your answers,it seems my problem is running open office in background!!! it dont runing on tcp/ip now!

peiman@digidoc:~$ sudo netstat -nap | grep office
unix  3      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2794171  4301/soffice.bin    /tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_84166f53c65d9ded4d416e24fa9b5d8

Comment: I did what 'apt-get' says and installed libreoffice-script-provider-python.  But that doesn't provide the package for python, from what I can tell.  'import uno' does not work.  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @noisygecko you need to use python 3, if I'm not mistaken, yeah, libreoffice-script-proveder-python installs `python3-uno` along.

Comment: The problem is I was wanting to use it from Enthought Canopy version of Python, which is still Python 2.7. It is very hard to move to Python 3 when trying to use all the science/research Python packages.  But I figured out an easier way to do what I want.

Comment: @noisygecko heh, did you send the patchs upstream?

Comment: I had same problem. I choose to use VM with old Mint distro. BUT: i found one nice solution in case you ned python-2 support very very much. Here is sh script to rebuild libreoffice with python-2 support. https://gist.github.com/hbrunn/6f4a007a6ff7f75c0f8b

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice python-genshi python-cairo python-lxml python-setuptools
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-script-provider-python
easy_install uno
```

Comment: What is `easy_install`?  Where does that come from?

Comment: easy_install is obsolete. It has been replaced by pip.
Python2 is no longer to be used for any project, so please follow the instructions in Braiam's answer above.