# python-Uno , No Module named Uno

Tags: python-2.7

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with python 2.7.6.

I am trying to install python-uno library which allows use of the standard LibreOffice API with the Python scripting language,but i am unable to find the uno library for python 2.7

Earlier when i was using Ubuntu 12.04, python-uno library was available.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/418225/how-do-i-resolve-a-python-uno-has-no-installation-candidate-error

Comment: Thanks for the link, but sadly python3-uno only works with python3, i want to use it with python2.7.6

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install libreoffice-script-provider-python

Comment: What is this command? what did this command using for?